# Prevent Ajax Response From Adding Backslashes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm passing some variables through to PHP using Ajax.

When I receive the response, they have backslashes before the 's.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
       var str = "Test's sample's string's.";

       $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'myAjax.php',
             data: {"data":str},
             success: function(response){
                 console.log(response);
             }
        });
```

And here is the plain old myAjax.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
   echo $_POST['data'];
 }
```

But for some reason the JavaScript logs:

```
  Test\'s sample\'s string\'s.
```

I want to prevent these backslashes from coming back in the Ajax response.

Please advise.

Comment: That's not AjaX.  You're on a BADLY out-of-date/obsolete PHP version that still thinks `magic_quotes` is a idea. magic_quotes was never nifty, and on a good day would barely qualify to aspire being a moronic idea.

Comment: My apologies. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Please try with echo stripslashes($_POST['data']);